# How to put a label on a recurrent arrow?

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, tikz-arrows, labels

I want to draw a recurrent layer of a rnn. Therefore I am using the following code but can't manage to put a label (\nu) on the recurrent arrow. The picture show my desired output, its simply a label missing.

Do you have any idea how to achieve this?

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
[   cnode/.style={draw=black,fill=#1,minimum width=3mm,circle},
]

    % add fourth input (n)
    \node[cnode=blue,label=180:$x$] (x) at (0,0) {};
    \node[cnode=gray,label=110:$x^{(1)}$] (h) at (0,2) {};
    \draw [->](x) -- node[right,pos=0.45] {$\omega$} (h);
    \draw [->](h) to [out=30,in=330,looseness=15] {$\nu$} (h);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `node[right]`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
[   cnode/.style={draw=black,fill=#1,minimum width=3mm,circle},
]

    % add fourth input (n)
    \node[cnode=blue,label=180:$x$] (x) at (0,0) {};
    \node[cnode=gray,label=110:$x^{(1)}$] (h) at (0,2) {};
    \draw [->](x) -- node[right,pos=0.45] {$\omega$} (h);
    \draw [->](h) to [out=30,in=330,looseness=15] node[right]{$\nu$} (h);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You could also work with `quotes`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
[   cnode/.style={draw=black,fill=#1,minimum width=3mm,circle},
]

    % add fourth input (n)
    \node[cnode=blue,label=180:$x$] (x) at (0,0) {};
    \node[cnode=gray,label=110:$x^{(1)}$] (h) at (0,2) {};
    \draw [->](x) -- node[right,pos=0.45] {$\omega$} (h);
    \draw [->](h) to [out=30,in=330,looseness=15,"$\nu$"]  (h);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: oh well that was easy, thank you :) I always kept trying to put the right argument in [out=30,in=330,looseness=15]...

Comment: @Quastiat You can do that if you load `quotes`. I added an example of that sort, too.